# Why can't you compile batch files?

Tags: batch-file, scripting, compilation

I think we all know that batch files can not be compiled. No compiler can turn your batch script source code into a compiled .exe in which there are no temp files lying around on your computer or the same batch code being placed somewhere else.
I get it. Batch is a scripting language. It runs all at once and needs to be interpreted by cmd.exe.

However other compilers for different languages compile their code into a solid executable file with executable code suited for machines to read.

My question is: How are other languages able to turn their code into steps that a machine can read, known as an exe file, whereas batch can not? Both are steps that the computer has to read and take.

Comment: Your question is not a request for help with your code, it is a general software question and as such should be deleted here and posted to [Super User](https://superuser.com/questions/ask) instead.

Comment: Oh dear, you're right. Sorry about that, got mixed up.

Comment: Batch is a list of instructions that users give computers. So instead of typing 5 lines they type a batch file name that runs those 5 lines. **This was the ONLY way to operate a computer**. It is the only efficient way of doing system administration tasks. Batch files are **NOT** a programming language, but what we used before Windows Explorer to tell the computer what to do. To begin with one **only** had a keyboard and printer, no monitor.

Comment: Other languages does _not_ depend on any additional module/support/whatever in order to execute, so the .exe file is complete. You may compile a .bat file into an independant .exe file if you include all the run-time features of `cmd.exe` into the created .exe file or, at least, the `cmd.exe` features that use the source Batch file...

Comment: Do you understand that with most shell scripting languages the commands are built-in to the interpreter.  There is nothing to compile because it is already compiled into the shells interpreter.

Comment: So then why hasn't someone already built some sort of translator from batch commands to some language in which you don't need cmd.exe to read the script?

Comment: Because doing that would require to _duplicate_ the `cmd.exe` behavior using the instructions of the base language, perhaps? Do you realize that `cmd.exe` is a 400 Kb size .exe program?

Comment: That's.. That's what I meant. I take `echo Hello World` and translate it to `print("Hello World)' and then since C/Python/CompilableLanguage can be compiled into a self running exe.

I mean with so many people on the internet, surely someone has thought of it.

Comment: Well, no... I invite you to try to "translate" the `for` Batch command into C or Phyton to realize by yourself why nobody has done it... (hint: if you do so, you will end with a compiler version of the source code of the `cmd.exe` interpreter that is written in C).